# I have a problem while installing mdk4 on Arch based system

Tags: arch-linux, make, manjaro, github, aircrack-ng

When I try to install /aicrack-ng/mdk4 I get:

`error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [Makefile:38: mdk4] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src' make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2`

This is the end of the output (since when I submit the whole output it is considered as a spam) when I run 'make' in the mdk4 folder.

```cc
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks'
make -C attacks
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=mdk4-v1 -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3  -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -fcommon  mdk4.c osdep/libosdep.a debug.o helpers.o mac_addr.o linkedlist.o greylist.o dumpfile.o packet.o brute.o osdep.o channelhopper.o ghosting.o fragmenting.o attacks/attacks.o attacks/auth_dos.o attacks/beacon_flood.o attacks/countermeasures.o attacks/deauth.o attacks/dummy.o attacks/eapol.o attacks/fuzzer.o attacks/ieee80211s.o attacks/probing.o attacks/wids.o -o mdk4 -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3  -lm -Losdep -losdep -lpthread -lpcap
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/auth_dos.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/beacon_flood.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/beacon_flood.c:34: multiple definition of `bssid'; attacks/auth_dos.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/auth_dos.c:50: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/beacon_flood.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/countermeasures.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/deauth.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/deauth.c:19: multiple definition of `bssid'; attacks/auth_dos.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/auth_dos.c:50: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/deauth.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/dummy.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/eapol.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/fuzzer.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/ieee80211s.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/probing.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attacks/wids.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: multiple definition of `attack_count'; attacks/attacks.o:/home/u4/mdk4/src/attacks/attacks.h:39: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:38: mdk4] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

- And then I found this solution on github:

Installation

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/mdk4
cd mdk4
make
sudo make install
# Using Arch Linux (and derived) append `CC=clang` after any `make` in commands.
```

But the thing is I have no idea how to do this

> append `CC=clang` after any `make` in commands.

I use manjaro with bspwm environment

What should I do?

edit: So I did the CC=clang thing and this time the error is slightly different:
 `error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make[1]: *** [Makefile:38: mdk4] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/u4/mdk4/src' make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2`

edit: The first screenshot is the beginning of the output and the seconde one is the end of the output.
[image: The beginning of the output]

[image: The end of the output]

Comment: If you're still getting errors with `make CC=clang`, it might be time to open a bug report upstream. It's possible there's something off about their documentation. That slight difference in the wording of the error message _sounds to me_ like it's the same error being reported by a different program (i.e., clangs's linker instead of whatever linker was being used before).

Comment: thanks I'll try that and I'll report if there's any changes

Comment: And where should I report it? Arch linux, CC=clang or manjaro.  @solarshado

Comment: Based on those screenshots, it looks like there might be some bad `.o` files, probably from the initial, failed `make`. Try a `make clean` before another `make CC=clang`. If that still dies with the same error, `rm` the whole source tree and start with a fresh `git clone`. If you're _still_ getting the same error after all that, file a bug with the aircrack project, being sure to include that second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You're running `make` directly, not via an AUR helper/`makepkg`, right? Then it should be as simple as running:

```
$ make CC=clang
[loads of output here]
$ sudo make install CC=clang
```

instead of

```
$ make
[loads of output here]
$ sudo make install
```

While I doubt the `make install` step strictly needs `CC` set, it shouldn't hurt anything to include it.

[This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2826178/2059482) explains the syntax and passing variable into `make` in more detail.

You might also need to [install clang](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clang#Installation) if you don't already have it; it doesn't look like it's part of Arch's `base-devel` group, I'm not sure about
Manjaro.

Comment: I installed clang but when I type: make clang in the mdk4 folder I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'clang'.  Stop.` I don't know, maybe the thing I found on github wasn't really a solution?

Comment: sounds like you ran `make clang` instead of `make CC=clang`. the first tells `make` to try to build a target named "clang", which the error message helpfully informs you doesn't exist. the second tells `make` to build the default target with the variable `CC` set to `clang`, overriding whatever default it would have used.

Comment: here I've attached 2 screenshots, if you want I can screenshot the entire code.